# Change parent of multiple child pages

Tags: nodes

I have a page with many child pages. And I have a task: there's needed to change parent for all of this child pages. I can move single page using "node hierarchy > Parent > Enter the title of the parent node." and write wanted node title there, but I can't use it for many pages. Is there solution for this problem? I tried to google it, but find nothing.

Comment: In that case I hope you structured your content using the book module. You can easily reorder the entire book on `/admin/structure/book`. If not, you will have to better explain how your content is structured. After all, we cannot guess how you've built your site :)

Comment: There's Node Hierarchy (https://www.drupal.org/node/302253) module used. Your comment opened my eyes because I hadn't been realizing that I didn't mention module name in my question!

Comment: That helps a little. It is also an indication that you are still on Drupal 7. I personally have no experience with this module so I cannot help you out. I also do not know how many pages you have, but considering the fact that the module seems to have been abandoned by its maintainers, you might want to consider moving to the book module that ships with Drupal. It will also help you upgrading to a newer Drupal version later on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your parent-child relationships are done through an Entity reference field on the child node pointing to a parent.

As always there is more than one way of solving it in Drupal but one popular way is to use the [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module.

The module [Views Bulk Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_edit) helps to speed it up by showing the field options to update.

The procedure is to create Views where you can see all the child nodes among the results. It can be all nodes of that type, or you can even create it specifically for one parent node where its children nodes are automatically filtered.

VBO allows you to add a Field to your Views that shows up as a checkbox next to each result row. It also adds an Action you can trigger on the chosen rows.

With that configured you will be able to choose nodes from your results and edit them in bulk.